# Python, argparse: turn off help description for selected parameters

Tags: python, argparse

Using `argparse`, is there a way to turn off the help descriptions for some selected parameters? I tried `add_help=False`, but it is in conflict with `help=myDescription`.

I would like to pass a boolean to decide whether or not I want a parameter to be displayed.

Is this possible?

Comment: _pass a boolean_ to what? You could use a boolean to decide how you build the argument list originally ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep.  In `add_argument`, just specify `help=argparse.SUPPRESS`.

example:

```
import argparse

args = ('foo','bar','baz','qux')    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

for x in args:
    parser.add_argument('--{0}'.format(x),help=x if x != 'baz' else argparse.SUPPRESS)

parser.parse_args(['-h'])
```

Now we see that `baz` is missing.